# pandas saves my data only into one column in a csv-file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have 2 lists and I want to save them in a csv file but they always end up in one column.

> dates=['13:14 - 28. Okt. 2019', '14:30 - 27. Okt. 2019', '11:33 - 26. Okt. 2019', '15:54 - 25. Okt. 2019']
>
> codes=['W9KBJ-95X9T-ZC3KW-BJTJT-5FF3T', 'CZWJJ-X6XHJ-9CJC5-JTT3J-WZ6WC', 'KZK3T-K6RSJ-ZWTCK-JTJ3T-T3HJJ', 'CHCBT-TF6HB-ZC3WC-BT333-KBR3B']

I checked the documentation but without success.

`def save_as_csv(codes, dates, save_location):
    raw_data = {'codes': codes, 'date_posted': dates}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=raw_data)
    df.to_csv(save_location, columns=['codes', 'date_posted'], index=False)`

## -----

> codes,date_posted
>
> W9KBJ-95X9T-ZC3KW-BJTJT-5FF3T,13:14 - 28. Okt. 2019
>
> CZWJJ-X6XHJ-9CJC5-JTT3J-WZ6WC,14:30 - 27. Okt. 2019
>
> KZK3T-K6RSJ-ZWTCK-JTJ3T-T3HJJ,11:33 - 26. Okt. 2019
>
> CHCBT-TF6HB-ZC3WC-BT333-KBR3B,15:54 - 25. Okt. 2019

This is my result, but they are all in one column.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (works on my end):

```
dates=['13:14 - 28. Okt. 2019', '14:30 - 27. Okt. 2019', '11:33 - 26. Okt. 2019', '15:54 - 25. Okt. 2019']

codes=['W9KBJ-95X9T-ZC3KW-BJTJT-5FF3T', 'CZWJJ-X6XHJ-9CJC5-JTT3J-WZ6WC', 'KZK3T-K6RSJ-ZWTCK-JTJ3T-T3HJJ', 'CHCBT-TF6HB-ZC3WC-BT333-KBR3B']


def save_as_csv(codes, dates, save_location):
    df = pd.DataFrame([dates, codes]).T
    df.columns = ['dates', 'code']
    df.to_csv(save_location, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems they are two columns already, as you gave example in your question

- codes[W9KBJ-95X9T-ZC3KW-BJTJT-5FF3T]
- date_posted[13:14 - 28. Okt. 2019]

read this file in pandas again, with explicit "," as a delimiter, you'll be able to read this file in CSV format.

Let me know if you are still not clear.

Thanks.